# Make alacritty the default terminal permanently

Tags: command-line, update-alternatives

Currently I use [`alacritty`](https://alacritty.org/) as default terminal emulator. On any given day this is the output of `update-alternatives`:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
There are 7 choices for the alternative x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator).

  Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/alacritty                70        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/alacritty                70        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/koi8rxterm               20        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/lxterm                   30        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/uxterm                   20        manual mode
  6            /usr/bin/xterm                    20        manual mode
  7            /usr/local/bin/termite            60        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

However, every time I run the updates the priorities in this list are automatically modified and `alacritty` stops being the default programme (and is removed from `auto mode`):

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
There are 7 choices for the alternative x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator).

 ​Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/local/bin/termite            60        auto mode
 ​1            /usr/bin/alacritty                50        manual mode
 ​2            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
 ​3            /usr/bin/koi8rxterm               20        manual mode
 ​4            /usr/bin/lxterm                   30        manual mode
 ​5            /usr/bin/uxterm                   20        manual mode
 ​6            /usr/bin/xterm                    20        manual mode
 ​7            /usr/local/bin/termite            60        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

It is possible to reset `alacritty` as the default terminal emulator with a
command like:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator /usr/bin/alacritty 70
```

Until the updates are run and it all gets back to square one. How can I prevent
the alternatives priorities from being modified automatically, setting `alacritty` permanently as the
default terminal emulator?

Answer (score 5):

**How to choose Alacritty as default terminal emulator.**

To launch Alacritty with the command to open its default terminal, it is necessary to define it as an alternative available for ‘terminal’ type applications:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator /usr/bin/alacritty 50
```

(The number ‘50’ at the end represents the priority of the entry)

Or try with `/usr/local/bin/alacritty` instead.

It will then be possible to define it as the default terminal, thanks to the command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Finally, if you want to remove alacritty from the available alternatives:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove "x-terminal-emulator" "/usr/bin/alacritty"
```

Or try again with `/usr/local/bin/alacritty` instead.

If the above commands shows error I believe you can open `dconf` Editor on default ubuntu desktop (gnome)

```
dconf-editor
```

(it will prompt to get installed at first)

and go to org > gnome > desktop > application > terminal and change gnome-terminal to the terminal of your choice.

[image]

You can do the same from command line with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec cmd_to_open_terminal_of_choice
```

With `cmd_to_open_terminal_of_choice` as 'alacritty' here, that is, without its path.

Just be careful and be sure you can restore the default which is also given in the dconf-editor menu if you forgot about it after a while.

When you now press Ctrl+Alt+T, 'alacritty' will open instead of 'gnome-terminal'.

**Hope it will helps you**

Answer (score 0):

As your first picture indicates by showing the starred zero and the "auto mode", the link group "x-terminal-emulator" is in *auto mode*.

What you want is to have it set to *manual mode*. This way, the alternative sticks regardless of the priority. You can achieve this by selecting "1" after your command of `$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`.

This way, the chosen `alacritty` should stay.

Comment: You might have missed this segment in the question: "every time I run the updates the priorities in this list are automatically modified and alacritty stops being the default programme".

Comment: I didn't miss it, but for me it was just describing the process which happens at auto mode. Something like "every time I run the updates, the priorities are set back to auto mode from manual mode and alacritty stops..." would have been clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Judging by the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647630 the following would work

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec /usr/bin/alacritty
```

This will work in gnome but your mileage may vary if you have a different DE.

Testing

```
nathans@skynet:~$ sudo gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec /usr/bin/terminator
[sudo] password for nathans: 
nathans@skynet:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-vaapi i965-va-driver intel-media-va-driver libaacs0 libaom0 libass9 libavcodec58 libavformat58 libavutil56 libbdplus0 libblas3 libbluray2
  libbs2b0 libchromaprint1 libcodec2-0.9 libdav1d4 libfftw3-double3 libflite1 libgme0 libgsm1 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libigdgmm11 liblilv-0-0 libllvm11 libmfx1 libmysofa1
  libnorm1 libopenmpt0 libpgm-5.3-0 libpostproc55 librabbitmq4 librubberband2 libserd-0-0 libshine3 libsnappy1v5 libsord-0-0 libsratom-0-0 libsrt1.4-gnutls libssh-gcrypt-4
  libswresample3 libswscale5 libudfread0 libva-drm2 libva-wayland2 libva-x11-2 libva2 libvidstab1.1 libx265-192 libxvidcore4 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 mesa-va-drivers
  ocl-icd-libopencl1 pocketsphinx-en-us va-driver-all
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  tzdata
1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 standard security update
Need to get 296 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,048 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64 tzdata all 2021a-2ubuntu0.21.04 [296 kB]
Fetched 296 kB in 0s (1,730 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 178432 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../tzdata_2021a-2ubuntu0.21.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking tzdata (2021a-2ubuntu0.21.04) over (2021a-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up tzdata (2021a-2ubuntu0.21.04) ...

Current default time zone: 'Europe/London'
Local time is now:      Wed Oct  6 15:36:18 BST 2021.
Universal Time is now:  Wed Oct  6 14:36:18 UTC 2021.
Run 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' if you wish to change it.

nathans@skynet:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator 
There are 2 choices for the alternative x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator).

  Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/terminator               50        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/terminator               50        manual mode
```

Updated answer to show the command functioning and running a system upgrade on ubuntu 21.04.